# Implementing Adword Remarketing with GTM Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I am implementing **GTM** in **Android** project which **will not use** GoogleAnalytics SDK or Adword SDK,but I want data in Google Analytics and Adword.

In order to achieve this,

1. I have implemented Google Anaytics tag in GTM,Added Rule {Always},
   Screen Name data is being sent to GTM which is reflected in Analytics,**This is tested and working properly**
2. I need InstallReferrals for Application which also should manage through **GTM**.
   To achieve this,
   Added a tag in **GTM for Adword** with the type **Adword Remarketing**,
   Added ConversionId and label from Adword.

   Added **tagmanager.InstallReferralService** and **tagmanager.InstallReferralReceiver** to Android manifest.xml.
   According to **source code of InstallReferralService** it passes data to **CampaignTrackingService** of **Analytics**,which should upload data to **Adword** and **Google Analytics**.
   But I am unable to get any data.
   Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong in this process.
3. I also need **Adword Conversion Tracking** to be used through GTM without Adword SDK.
   Not sure how to achieve this.